# Configuring Windows Client for NFS

Tags: nfs, windows-10

this question is about configuring Windows 10 Client for NFS. There are two parts to it, 1) map the export (drive), 2) set IM
Let's have NFS export (/media/NFS_share 192.168.0.*(rw,async)) already present and running properly, verified from another *nix boxes sharing same network range. Now, for mounting the export on Windows box we need Services for NFS installed and simply mount:

```
mount.exe 192.168.0.2:/media/NFS_share *
```

Command unfortunately results in:

```
Network Error - 53
Type 'NET HELPMSG 53' for more information.
```

Which is clearly incorrect:

```
PS C:\Users> showmount -e 192.168.0.2
Exports list on 192.168.0.2:
/media/NFS_share                   192.168.0.*
```

So, 1) what is the issue with the mounting? 'Path not found' is somehow misleading message.

Next step would be setting identity mapping. While there are multiple ways, I chose local passwd and group files. But IdentityMapping log in ServicesForNFS-Client event log do not mention files at all, insisting on failed AD connection like there are no passwd/group files present in %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc.
2) Are local files ment for Server only? Should AnonymousUid/Gid registry setting be used for client instead?

/edit: It would be worth of mentioning that opening \192.168.0.2 in Windows explorer shows the share as \media\NFS_share but clicking it results in 'access denied' error, which seems to be more appropriate than err 53.

Comment: Do you have a solution? Got exactly the same problem 

Comment: As a matter of fact I did, yes, but it's been a while as you can see, I need to discover the setup. Which part gives you trouble? Mounting or authentication?

Comment: I believe the solution was simply to use kinda obscure format for a mount path, like in case of smb: \\server_name\FULL_remote_path_from_root\dest_folder

Comment: I only got this problem with NFS4. So actually Windows10 has not a built in support for that.

Comment: @Ren if you have the solution then please post an answer.

Comment: @buhtz It's been years and I moved to Samba not long after this. But anyway, for error 53 in my case, the solution was as stated above, to map in Windows with full path to root of unix box: \\server_name\FULL_remote_path_from_root\dest_folder